# Intellij idea vim: cannot write selected text in visual mode to buffer file in osx

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, vim

I'm using intellij idea 2017 with the vim plugin. I'd like to be able to select a block of text in visual mode, write it to a buffer file like so:

```
:'<'>w! ~/xfer
```

Then I could access that block of text in a separate vim window in the terminal. My problem is that on my laptop (os x) it does not create a file at all. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

ideavim is not vim. Its `:w` doesn't support `[range]w {file}` So you cannot do it with ideavim.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve the same result though?